# How to determine the ratio of AC:AB?

Tags: geometry

While I was working through a sum related equilibrium of a body I came across this gemetric proof which I was unable to prove. It is given that AG=GB. I need to show that the ratio AC:AB=1:3. [image]

*My working *

I drew a scale diagram to check if the ratio is correct. and then I found that when drawn to scale the ratio fits well. As a start I let the angle AB which makes with horizontal as $\theta$ and I let AB as $2a$.So far I was only able to determine AX=$a\cos{\theta}$ and AD=$2a\cos{\theta}$. How should I proceed? Thanks in advance!

P.S: note that red corners are shown to indicated that they are perpendicular. DCX is also a straight line. Please excuse my untidy sketch. I had to draw it on paint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a perpendicular from $B$ to $AX$, to say $F$. Then $BF=AD$. You have similar triangles $AGX$ and $ABF$, so $GX=\frac12BF=\frac12AD$, and $AG=\frac12AB$. Then $\triangle ADC$ is similar to $\triangle GXC$. This yields $AC=2CG$. Can you finish?

Comment: Yes thank you. now I can work out the rest, this means AC=2a/3 and so AC:AB will be 1:3.